# Comparing Datasets in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have two sets of monthly data, and I'm trying to determine how this data changes each month.

For example:

Column A is a list of identifiers

Column B is a score (1 through 5) for each identifier

Both column A and column B change month-to-month.

How can I determine the number of identifiers in each 1-5 bucket that are the same and different in month t+1 vs month t=0?

Thanks!

Comment: Should the output be a 'total number', without doing anything with each case? Do the 'sets' in discussion ar identical in terms of identifiers (their number and their value)? How many records (rows) are involved?

Comment: Totals should be fine (i.e. # of identifiers that have moved into score 1 + # identifiers that have moved out of score 1 = total for score 1 for any given month). The identifiers are largely similar each month but do see some changes over time.

Comment: As of now I've concatenated the identifiers+score to create a unique single variable that seems easier to work with, just not sure how to compare the counts between month t+1 and month t=0 in a way that's scalable.

Comment: So, to compare whatever you have in column B:B would be ok? Are the identifiers in the same order?

Comment: I think so? I should be able to tweak the code to work with my formatting, I'm honestly just not sure where to conceptually start

Comment: Are the identifiers arranged in the same order in both sheets to be compared? I suppose that they are unique? Correct?

Comment: No, not always in the same order but yes they are unique in each column. The ordering part is what has tripped me up.

Comment: Then, test my answer code. I must leave now from my office. The code is untested...

Comment: Thank you! This will give me somewhere to start at a minimum

Answer (score 1):

Please, try the next code:

```
Sub ScoresCompare()
  Dim sh0 As Worksheet, sh As Worksheet, lastRow As Long
  Dim iCount As Long, i As Long, j As Long
  
  Set sh0 = ActiveSheet 'use here the reference one
  Set sh = Workbooks("To be checked").Worksheets(1) 'use here the sheet of the workbook to be checked
  lastRow = sh0.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
  For i = 2 To lastRow
    For j = 2 To lastRow
        If sh0.Range("A" & i).Value = sh.Range("A" & j).Value Then
            If sh0.Range("B" & i).Value <> sh.Range("B" & j).Value Then
                iCount = iCount + 1: Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next j
  Next i
  MsgBox "There are " & iCount & " differences. " & _
                  lastRow - 1 - iCount & " are unchanged..."  
End Sub
```